Нужно добавить фото в сообщение телеграмм бот, telebot
Мне нужно что бы фото и текст отправлял бот одним сообщением, но варианты как я думал это можно сделать не сработали , выдает ошибку, помогите пж 

Попробовал как советовал человек ниже , ошибка все равно , вставил скриншот кода , мб тут проблем

ниже вам дали вполне рабочий вариант, какую ошибку вы получаете - не понятно, вы ее не указали
